Why installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions will get Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory?
I'm testing out IMemoryCache to implement caching to the system. I found that when I triggered the Quick Actions by using Ctrl + ., the Quick Actions menu shows:

May I know why installing Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions will get Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory?

See the doc page for IMemoryCache:

Namespace: Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
Assembly: Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
Package: Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions v9.0.0-preview.4.24266.19

So IMemoryCache comes from the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions package, and it lives in the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory namespace.
This is why you're being prompted to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions package, and add using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.
Remember that a namespace is just the first part of a fully-qualified type name. You can have types which have the same namespace spread across multiple assemblies.

I think reading another page, which doesn't have the details as you shared. Thanks for that! Initially I was thinking the concept of abstract class, which we can't directly initialize the abstract class but we need to use the concrete class. I was thinking maybe Memory is something like a concrete class.

IMemoryCache is an interface, which is a form of abstraction (in that it hides the concrete cache implementation)

@IT_Guy If I answered your question, please consider accepting this answer using the button on the left
